# Spliting two different @All of items and then combining them according to same indexes. Total number of indexes are same in both @All of items

Tags: javascript, podio

```
individualproduct = @All of Transaction Product Name+'';
productitem= individual_product.split(',');
individual_quantity = @All of Transaction Quantity+''
quantityitem = individualquantity.split(',')+'';
for(count=0;count<productitem.length;count++)
{
var combine += productitem[count]+'' + quantity_item[count]+'';
}
```

It does not work. If we do it like :

```
for(count=0;count<productitem.length;count++)
{

productitem[count]+'' + quantity_item[count]+'';
}
```

It does not show an error. but through this, I can only get value at last index. we are expecting to get them all.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to achieve, what do you need to do?

When you assign `@All of Transactional Product Name` to `individualproduct`, you can't append `' '` since it's an array. Same for `individual_quantity`.

Is this what you wanted?

```
individualProduct = @All of Product Name;
individualQuantity = @All of Quantity;

var combine = '';
for(i = 0; i < individualProduct.length; i++) {
   combine += individualProduct[i] + ' ' + individualQuantity[i] + ' ';
}

combine;
```

First two lines, you get a reference to the names and quantities. Then, you iterate through each item, combining the name and the quantity.